# Why are these regular expressions not working?

Tags: regex, python-3.6, mathematical-expressions

I want a regex to match complex mathematical expressions.
However I will ask for an easier regex because it will be the simplest case.

**Example** input:
1+2+3+4

I want to separate each char:
`[('1', '+', '2', '+', '3', '+', '4')]`

With a **restriction**: there has to be at least one operation (i.e. `1+2`).

My regex: `([0-9]+)([+])([0-9]+)(([+])([0-9]+))*`
or `(\d+)(\+)(\d+)((\+)(\d+))*`

**Output** for `re.findall('(\d+)(\+)(\d+)((\+)(\d+))*',"1+2+3+4")`
:

> [('1', '+', '2', '+4', '+', '4')]

**Why is this not working? Is Python the problem?**

Comment: Your regex is (pseudo) `N+(+N)*`. It should be `N+N(+N)*`

Comment: Yes sorry, I copied the wrong one. See last edit

Comment: This is not the way. What you really need is a 2 step. Validate test it for `^\d+(?:\+\d+)*$` then match with findall `\+|\d+`. Otherwise, if python doesn't support the `\G` anchor, you might as well just use split().

Comment: And if you require at least 1 operation, test it with `^\d+\d+(?:\+\d+)*$` Just so you know, parsing _complex_ math expressions is quite a task.

Comment: This cannot be captured in a single group

Comment: Could you please @sln explain me how to do that 2 step? Thanks :)

Comment: @OscarMartinez  - Posted as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go the test route.
See if its valid using *re.match*
then just get the results with *re.findall*

Python code

```
import re

input = "1+2+3+4";
if re.match(r"^\d+\+\d+(?:\+\d+)*$", input) :
    print ("Matched")
    print (re.findall(r"\+|\d+", input))

else :
    print ("Not valid")
```

Output

```
Matched
['1', '+', '2', '+', '3', '+', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need ([0-9]+)([+])([0-9]+)(**?:**([+])([0-9]+))*

you get the '+4' for the group is out the last two expressions **(**([+])([0-9]+)**)**.

the **?:** indicate to python dont get de string for this group in the output.

Comment: And why is that regex ignoring `+3`?

Comment: Because this `(?:([+])([0-9]+))*` resets the capture groups on each quantified pass, that's why it can't be done this way...